# Gwibber on Ubuntu doesn't open

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

Gwibber Doesn't open .
When I tried to Open it from Command Line
I got this error

```
  ** (gwibber:3752): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowState' as
  enum when in fact it is of type
  'GFlags'

  ** (gwibber:3752): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowActions'
  as enum when in fact it is of type
  'GFlags'

  ** (gwibber:3752): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype
  'WnckWindowMoveResizeMask' as enum
  when in fact it is of type 'GFlags' No
  dbus monitor yet Updating...

  ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on
  com.Gwibber.Service:/com/gwibber/Service:
  dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
  org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply:
  Message did not receive a reply
  (timeout by message bus) Traceback
  (most recent call last):   File
  "/usr/bin/gwibber", line 67, in
  <module>
      client.Client()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gwibber/client.py",
  line 447, in __init__
      self.w = GwibberClient()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gwibber/client.py",
  line 29, in __init__
      self.model = gwui.Model()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gwibber/gwui.py",
  line 43, in __init__
      self.services = json.loads(self.daemon.GetServices()) 
  File
  "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/proxies.py",
  line 68, in __call__
      return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/proxies.py",
  line 140, in __call__
      **keywords)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/connection.py",
  line 620, in call_blocking
      message, timeout) dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
  org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply:
  Message did not receive a reply
  (timeout by message bus)
```

I tried to remove it and to Install again
but It has the same error

It was Working probably , then suddenly it didn't

Answer (score 1):

It's not gwibber, it's [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) that is in trouble. I'd be surprised if gwibber was the only service having problems.

You could do some detective work like see that dbus-daemon is running and active with `dbus-monitor` or you could try the somewhat more risky:

```
sudo apt-get purge libdbus-1-3 dbus
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-3 dbus
```

I'm still finding Lucid a little less than robust, but I've not seen dbus fail.